# Did Bilam lose the power of prophecy?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, nevua-prophecy, bilam

In [Bamidbar 24:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.24.14?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), Bilam says "I go back to my people," and Rashi explains that he knew Hashem had departed from him, and he was now like the rest of his people. Presumably this means he lost the power of prophecy. How, then, did he continue to prophesy about the Jewish People in the very next verses?

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in [Sanhedrin 106a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.106a.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> א"ר יוחנן בתחלה נביא ולבסוף קוסם
>
> Rabbi Yocḥanan said: Initially he was a prophet, (but ultimately, he lost his capacity for prophecy) and in the end was (merely) a diviner.

Whilst [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.106a.17?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.106a.17.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) over there notes:

> ולבסוף - שנתן עיניו לקלל את ישראל ניטלה ממנו נבואה ונעשה קוסם
>
> And in the end - when he turned his eyes to curse Israel, prophecy was taken from him and he was made a Diviner.

The [Ben Yehoyada](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.106a.17?lang=bi&p2=Ben_Yehoyada_on_Sanhedrin.106a.10&lang2=bi) makes your observation and writes:

> בַּתְּחִלָּה נָבִיא וּלְבַסּוֹף קוֹסֵם . פירש רש"י ז"ל אחר שנתן עיניו לקלל את ישראל. וקשא לפירושו והלא כל דברי הנבואה אשר נכתבה בתורה על שמו היו אחר שנתן עיניו לקלל? על כן יש לפרש אחר שנתן עצה לבלק להחטיא את ישראל ושוב ראיתי להרמ"ה בשיטה שפירש כן
>
> In the beginning he was  a prophet and in the end he was a diviner. Rashi explains, and this is his words - "after he turned his eyes to curse Israel". And there is a difficulty according to his explanation - aren't all the words of prophecy that are written in the Torah about him (lit. his name) after he turned his eyes to curse? Therefore, one would have to explain that (he only became a diviner and lost his prophecy) after he gave his advice to Balak to cause Israel to sin. And I saw this explanation as brought by the [Ramah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Abulafia#:%7E:text=Meir%20Abulafia%20is%20commonly%20known,%2Dee%2D%C9%99%3B%20c.).

Comment: But according to Rashi on chumash, both Hashem's departure and Bilam's advice to Balak happened before his final prophecy, assuming the events occurred in order.